# jQuery add class to nearest element which exists multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like this:

```
<span class="side">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
        <li><span class="copy-short-url"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></span></li>
        <span class="confirm">Copied!</span>
    </ul>
</span>

...

<span class="side">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
        <li><span class="copy-short-url"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></span></li>
        <span class="confirm">Copied!</span>
    </ul>
</span>

...

<span class="side">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
        <li><span class="copy-short-url"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></span></li>
        <span class="confirm">Copied!</span>
    </ul>
</span>

...

<span class="side">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
        <li><span class="copy-short-url"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></span></li>
        <span class="confirm">Copied!</span>
    </ul>
</span>
```

I now want to add a class to the span "confirm". But only for the span that belongs to the corresponding code block. So when I click on the second span "copy-short-url" only the second span "confirm" must get the additional class.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you are in the click event handler for `.copy-short-url`

```
$(this).closest('.side').find('.confirm').addClass('whatever');
```

`closest()` goes up the dom tree through parents until it finds a match.
`find()` goes down through children finding all matches.

Edit: In regard to your timeout question in the comments.

```
var $confirm = $(this).closest('.side').find('.confirm');
$confirm.addClass('whatever');
setTimeout(function(){ $confirm.removeClass('whatever'); }, 2000);
```

Comment: Great thank you! I now need to automatically remove the added class after 2 seconds. I thought it would work with something like:     $('.copy-short-url').on("click", function(){
      $(this).closest('.side').find('.confirm').addClass("show");
        setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).closest('.side').find('.confirm').removeClass("show");
      }, 2000);
    }); But it won't disappear. It stays forever.